# No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable error after build apk

Tags: flutter

i get this errror after flutter build apk; [!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
here is flutter doctor;

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale
    tr-TR)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ ANDROID_HOME = /Users/emresural/Users/emresural/Library/Android/sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

my .zshrc file;

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Users/emresural/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/emresural/development/flutter/bin"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/emresural/Library/Android/sdk
```

i tried run flutter get apk and i get
No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.

Comment: I tried old titles, none of them worked

Comment: Did you check your sdk installation in Android Studio first ?